# my images and styles are not rendering

Tags: php, html, css

I am not sure why my images and style are not rendering. I have tried ../../, I have tried without the / and I have tried just ../.

This is my index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MicroUrb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles.css">
</head>
<body id="final-example">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="banner">
            <a href="/" title="Return to Home">
                <img src="img/banner.png" alt="MicroUrb">
            </a>
        </div><!-- banner -->

            <div id="nav">

            </div><!-- nav -->
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="footer" class="cf">
                        <div class="column three">
                            <strong>Phone</strong>
                            609.505.3395
                        </div><!-- column -->
                        <div class="column three">
                            <strong>Location</strong>
                            <!-- location to go here -->
                        </div><!-- column -->
                        <div class="column three last">
                            <strong>Hours</strong>
                            <em>Tuesday - Thursday</em><br>
                            1:00pm - 9:00pm<br><br>
                            <em>Friday and Saturday</em><br>
                            4:00pm - 11:00pm<br><br>
                            <em>Sunday - Monday</em>
                            Closed<br><br>
                        </div><!-- column -->
                    </div><!-- footer -->
                    <small>&copy;2017 MicroUrb</small>
                </div><!-- content -->


    </div><!-- wrapper -->
    <div class="copyright-info">
        <?php includes('../assets/includes/copyright.php'); ?>
    </div><!-- copyright-info -->

</body>
</html>
```

This is the part of my css file that is not rendering inside styles.css:

```
body {
    background: #f5f4f1 url('/assets/img/bg.jpg');
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #353535;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
```

And this is my file structure:

[image]

Comment: What is the document root in your virtual host? Your vhost or htaccess will usually prevent moving up in the directory path. Try using `/img/bg.jpg` instead.

Comment: @JeremyHarris, the /img/bg.jpg did not work, but I tried this <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css"> removing the first / from in front of assets and that worked. So now it is pulling the styles.css file correctly, but within the styles.css I still can't get it to grab the bg.jpg.

Comment: It should be relative. Does this work with the dot in front of the slash? `background-image: url('./img/bg.jpg');`

Comment: @JeremyHarris, it works when I remove this: #f5f4f1 from in between background-image: and url();  So post your responses as the answer.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using paths in CSS, it should be relative to the CSS file. So the following should work:

```
background: #f5f4f1 url('./img/bg.jpg');
```

You said that having the color there first doesn't work, but without it, it does. That doesn't make a lot of sense because the order of that value doesn't matter. There are [only a few exceptions](http://sixrevisions.com/css/background-css-shorthand/) in the shorthand `background` property.

Regardless, you can always just do this:

```
background-color: #F5F4F1;
background-image: url('./img/bg.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
./img/banner.png
```

So you are in the styles.css and want to render an image on the index.php page.  It's a directory behind so:

```
 url('../images/image.png');
```

Also try using

```
 background-image
```

instead of

```
 background.
```

Comment: unbelieveable, I tried your suggestions and nothing is working.

Comment: Are you getting any error on the image? If not then It could be that some other styling is conflicting and you are simply not seeing anything.  Comment out everything on the html page and leave the body. Work on the background image alone.

Comment: If I were you I would add the styling directly on the html just to prove that it's your path that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your code and got the picture showing and i think the css seems to be working. When i change the values they change on the page. I hope you see the file structure below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>MicroUrb</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stack.css">
</head>

body {
    background:url('../img/yvette.jpg');
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
 }
```

[image: file structure i used]

Good luck